# Cake PHP file Downloading using Media view

Tags: cakephp

Hi I uploaded files and stored in app/views/xxx/yyy.
  Now i would like to download the files
  If the file is PDF it is opened in new Tab and rest of them are downloaded, I need all files to be opened in new tab.

Here is my Code :

```
$this->view = 'Media';
$params = array(
    'id' => $fileName,
    'name' => $fileNameWOExtn,
    'download' => false,
    'extension' => $fileExtn,  // must be lower case
    'path' => APP . 'views' . DS .'static' . DS. $url .DS  // don't forget terminal 'DS'                    
);
LogUtil::$logger->debug('Media View Params : '. var_export($params, true));

$this->set($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not every file can be opened in the browser. A lot of file type encodings are proprietary and require their specific program to read and interpret them. PDFs, plain text files, some images, etc (with some exceptions) are the only types that browsers can recognize.

What types are files are you trying to render?